# Is it okay to register all table view cells in a base table view class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I think this is not an opinionated question, but rather a question made to know if this is a good practice or not in iOS.

I'm currently doing this registration of custom `tableViewCells` in every `controller` in my project.

```
// MARK: Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    self.tableView.register(R.nib.customCellXX)
    self.tableView.register(R.nib.customCellYY)
    // and so on...

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

I'm just wondering if I could just make a subclass of `tableView` and register there all the custom `tableViewCells` I have as well as put the auto-height of the `tableView` + `tableHeaderView` + `tableFooterView`. In this case, I'm reducing the line of codes in my `controllers` and avoiding redundancies.

**EDIT:** If this is a good practice, where can I put the registration of the custom cells in my subclassed `BaseTableView`?

Comment: This can be done that way. You can register all the cells in that custom tableview. Let me know if you need an example

Comment: Yea, see the edited question, where should I put the registration of the custom cells in my subclassed `BaseTableView`? Inside the `didMoveToWindow()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in the following way:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style {

      self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style];

      if (self) {
         [self registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"reUseIdentifier"];
      }

      return self;
}
```

Later, you can subclass this `UITableView` or even use this in different controllers.

Comment: I'm registering my custom cells inside the `didMoveToWindow()` and before calling the `super.didMoveToWindow()`. It works fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You COULD, as long as you call `super.viewDidLoad()`, inside of the child VC's overridden `viewDidLoad` methods. That said, subclassing VCs is generally bad practice in iOS.

If you use **Interface Builder**, the `IBOutlets` you wire up from your `Storyboard` to your `.swift` files, all have identifying values, and can cause `nil` reference crashes, and cause **build errors**.

If you're trying to use the same `IBOutlets` across multiple `VCs`, which you will necessarily do if you try to wire any `UI` element to your parent VC.

If you want all of your VCs to have some **shared SIGNATURE** (i.e., the same methods or properties), create a **custom protocol**. If you want them all to have access to the same `UI` elements in Interface Builder, learn to use `Storyboards`.

You can create a VC in a Storyboard, and instantiate it in code, easily.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know having a `BaseViewController` is a bad practice in iOS. I have that kind of class to set the `viewController`'s default configuration, like removing the navigation title, setting the status bar to default, and etc... Of course I know how to use Storyboards. And there's no `viewDidLoad()` in `UITableView`.

Comment: I've seen it several times, and there are uses for it, but the general rule for reused behavior in Swift is: if you can do it with protocols, do it with protocols. And reused UI elements are not a good use for inheritance. If you want to reuse the same custom UIView, you can use a .xib and/or a custom class, and add it to multiple VCs with little trouble or excessive memory usage.

Comment: Also, sorry that's vague. When to use inheritance in Swift is a complicated problem. if you'd like an example of a relatively complicated project, that has shared behavior but very little inheritance, I can provide a link to an app I'm building for a friend.

Comment: Ok, so currently, I have multiple `viewControllers` in a storyboard. Some of those `viewControllers` have `tableViews` inside. It's not good to assign to these `tableViews` my `BaseTableView`? Sure, I would be so glad to check that out.

Comment: @dylanthelion I think this is a litte bit incorrect. You almost always subclass viewcontrollers, even the Xcode templates suggest it. Just try adding a new viewcontroller, it will always be something like `class MyViewController : UIViewController`. So from my understanding subclassing (view controllers) is very common in Cocoa (Touch). What you do with protocols is the interaction with the views, at least those which are a litte more complex.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen: That's correct. But there's a difference between subclassing UIViewController, UITableViewController, etc..., and creating another parent VC for most or all of your app's VC's (what the OP is trying to do). The OP was asking about best practices in Swift, and using VC inheritance to handle shared behavior is not best practice. Do you disagree? Or do you think I did not communicate myself well enough.

Comment: Yeah! according to me just create a `UItableView` class and and `init` you cell there. so whenever you call that `customTableClass` it automatically initiate your cell too. and for better assign this custom to your `tableView` from `storyboard`.

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com: If you're talking about a custom UIView, and not reusing controllers, that's fine. That said, I can't think of a reason to reuse a custom UITableView (please correct me if you have a good reason), and everything I said, I insist is true for UIViewControllers. Generally, you DO reuse custom/subclassed UITableViewCells, at which point I reiterate: learn to do this with IB, if you haven't already; it's pretty easy.

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com If you are doing `inheritance` as @dydylanthelion said then you can do it. But if you don't do this thats better. Because you are going to do multiple `inheritance` which is not possible so to compensate this you have made changes for every super class.